# Show that the union of two sets, each of measure zero, has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the union  of two sets, each of measure zero, has  measure zero

I have some ideas but not sure if it is sufficient.

Let f be a set of discontinuities on function f and let g be a set of discontinuities function g.

Thm states that if f and g are continuous at number a, then the sum is continuous.

Since f and g have measure zero,

$m(f \cup g) \leq (f+g)$

Thus f+g have measure zero, the union must have measure zero.

Comment: are $f$ and $g$ functions or sets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With outer measure $\mu^*$ we have $$\mu^*(F \cup G) = \mu^*(F) + \mu^*(G)$$  since $\{A_n\}$ covers $F \cup G$ if and only if it covers $F$ and $G$.